# Does the inequality $|\frac{1-x}{(\sqrt x +1)^2}|<1$ hold for $x>0$?

Tags: functions, inequality, absolute-value

I drew the graph of the function and I think the inequality is true but I don't know how prove it, can you help me please?

Comment: The denominator is $x + 2 \sqrt x + 1$, so it suffices to show that $|1-x| < 1+x$ for $x \ge 0$ – do you know the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<0$, the fraction is undefined.

For $x=0$ you have equality

$$\frac{1-0}{(\sqrt 0 +1)^2}=1$$

for $x >0$ you have

$$|(\sqrt x +1)^2| = x+ 2 \sqrt x +1 > x+1= |-x|+|+1|\ge|1-x|$$
(where the last inequality follows by the triangle inequality). This is equivalent to
$$\left| \frac{1-x}{(\sqrt x +1)^2} \right| <1$$

Comment: Thank you, and if I change the function to $\left| \frac{1-x}{(1-\sqrt x )^2} \right| $ then $\left| \frac{1-x}{(1-\sqrt x )^2} \right|>1? $ To prove it I should use the same method ?

Comment: No, this does not work for this second function. You need to split the two cases $x<1$ and $x>1$ and study them separately.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you check this question too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750303/solve-inequality-left-frac1-lambdaa12-right1

Answer (score 1):

Since there is $\sqrt{x}$ then we have $x \ge 0$.

$$|1-x| < x+1+2\sqrt{x}$$

If $x \le 1$,

$$1-x \le x+1 + 2\sqrt{x}$$

$$0 \le x + \sqrt{x}$$

If $x > 1$, we have

$$x-1 \le x+1 + 2\sqrt{x}$$

$$-1 \le \sqrt{x}$$

which is again true.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\geq 0$, since both sides are non-negative, then the inequality is equivalent to
$$(\sqrt{x}+1)^2(\sqrt{x}-1)^2=(x-1)^2\leq (\sqrt{x}+1)^4,$$
that is (note that $(\sqrt{x}+1)\not =0$),
$$x-2\sqrt{x}+1=(\sqrt{x}-1)^2\leq (\sqrt{x}+1)^2=x+2\sqrt{x}+1$$
which is always satisfied for $x\geq 0$.