# Solve inequality $\left|\frac{1-\lambda}{(a+1)^2}\right|<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Let $a,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda>0$
$$f(x)=\frac{x+\lambda}{x+1}$$
$$a=\frac{a+\lambda}{a+1}\Rightarrow a^2=\lambda\Rightarrow a=\pm\sqrt\lambda$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\lambda}{(x+1)^2}$$

I want to know when $|f'(a)|<1 $, so first I calculate $|f'(a)| $ :
$$|f'(a)|=\left|\frac{1-\lambda}{(a+1)^2}\right|=\left|\frac{1-a^2}{(a+1)^2}\right|=\left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|$$

Then I solved the inequality $|f'(a)|<1$:
$$\left|\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|<1\Rightarrow  -1<\frac{1-a}{1+a}<1\Rightarrow$$
$$0<\frac{2}{1+a}\,\hspace{0.25cm}   \text{and}\hspace{0.25cm} \frac{2a}{1+a}>0 $$
$$-1<a\,\hspace{0.25cm}   \text{and}\hspace{0.25cm} (-1>a  \hspace{0.25 cm}   \text{or} \hspace{0.25cm}a>0) $$
$$\boldsymbol{a>0}
$$
So $a$ should be $a=\sqrt\lambda$ to  $|f'(a)|<1$.

Is my work correct? or Is there a nother way to do it?

Comment: For what variable want you to solve this inequality?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner for $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can write $$\sqrt{|1-\lambda|}\le |a+1|$$ So you have two cases:
$$a\geq -1$$ then you will get $$\sqrt{|1-\lambda|}-1\le a$$
And if $$a<-1$$ then you will get $$\sqrt{|1-\lambda|}\le -a-1$$ or
$$a\le -\sqrt{|1-\lambda|}-1$$

Comment: So my work is wrong?, It doesn't matter the relation between $\lambda$ and $a$ that I wrote previously to the inequality?

Comment: You have asked for an other way, and this is my way.